# Javascript, modify content of a subelement without an id

Tags: javascript

I need to modify the content of a subelement. Unfortunately this element has no id.

The structure is:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="level0 nav5">
        <a class="top-menu">
            <span> CONTENT NEEDS MODFIED </span>
```

The only difference is always the li class. I can get access via CSS by

```
#nav li.level0.nav-5 a span { }
```

But I can't get access via Javascript. Following is **wrong**

```
var str = document.getElementById("level0.nav5").innerHTML;
str.children('span').eq(0).text()
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!!

Comment: getElementById gets element by an id, and you are passing invalid class selector. Did you mean querySelectorAll with ".level0.nav5."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `querySelector`

```
document.querySelector('#nav li.level0 a span').innerHTML = 'Something else'
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/PQxNY/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get at elements by using querySelectorAll:

`var element = document.querySelectorAll("a.top-menu span");`

Answer (score 0):

Try

instead of this

```
<li class='level0 nav5'>
```

this

```
<li id='level0 nav5'>
```

Because with getElementById('level0 nav5') you're looking for the level0 nav5 id, but it doesn't exist. So by changing the class to an id it should work.

If you'd really don't like to use the id, try looking into jQuery in which it can be called by simply doing this.

```
$('.level0 nav5')
```

Using jQuery you can achieve quite a lot of neat things. So try looking into that.